# How do you create custom dashboards in AWS Pinpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

AWS Pinpoint Analytics appears to have replaced Amazon Mobile Analytics.  In Mobile Analytics, you were able to [create custom dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/creating-dashboards.html).

I'm struggling to find the feature in AWS Pinpoint.  I'm assuming it's in there somewhere, but alas, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@D.Patrick, you can create custom dashboards with Pinpoint data but not directly within Pinpoint console **i.e** You would need first to export your Pinpoint event data to a persistent storage **(e.g S3 or Redshift)** using Amazon [Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/analytics-streaming.html). Once in S3, you can use analytics tools to further analyze or visual the data. Such analytic tool offered by AWS include AWS [Quicksight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-data-set-s3.html) or AWS [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/). Other analytics(none-AWS) tools include [Splunk](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/integrating-splunk-with-amazon-kinesis-streams/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the blog by AWS on this topic:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/creating-custom-pinpoint-dashboards-using-amazon-quicksight-part-1/

The 3 parts of this session describe in detail how to use Python 3, with AWS Lambda to create the custom dashboards.